# Weird Asset Pipeline Issue ( Path contained in CSS file does not match what chrome inspect shows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

This one has me stumped. I am using rails with nginx.

When I examine the CSS file directly using chromes dev tools, the correct asset path is there eg: `assets/image-kdjfdklfjhsldfh.png`. The correct path is also there when I look at the files in public/assets and when I go to the file by copy pasting it into my browser I am able to view it with no problem.

However, none of the images from my css file show up at all, and when I go to inspect element (right click -inspect), the elements have the incorrect path `assets/image.png` ....even though the CSS file (I click on the link that takes you to the line, within inspect) shows the path is there.

So the path in the css file (the correct one) does not seem to be the actual path that the browser is using (I didn't even think that was possible).

I have tried recompiling my assets, restarting the server, as well as clearing my on my own browser, I still have the same issue, I have tried firefox and its the same thing?

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had a different CSS file for the admin section of the site that was overriding the style, how I didn't spot this before I don't know..

Also if its any help to others, I also found out that inspect can be different to the source code because the source code is what the browser received prior to any javascript. Inspect shows 'live' css, that may be affectr